# Use Regular Expression To Identify Identical Strings in Java

Tags: java, regex

Sorry for probably a dumb question but I'm completely new to regular expression.

I have to identify whether some strings are identical given a pattern, is it possible to use regular expression to identify the pattern below? These strings should be treated the same in my project.

```
foo
foo(1)
foo(2)
foo(1)(1)
foo(1)(2)

foo(any number)(any number)(...)(...)
```

Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Guessing something like this should do it: `foo(\([0-9]*\))*` anything between `()` is a group and `*` indicates it can repeat 0 or more times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/uNVAUw/1), `[A-Za-z]+(?:\(\d+\))*` which can be explained as follows:

- `[A-Za-z]+`: Any alphabets one or more times
- `(?:`: Start of non-capturing group

  - `\(`: The character `(`
  - `\d+`: One or more digits
  - `\)`: The character `)`
- `)`: End of non-capturing group
- `*`: Zero or more times

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
([A-z]+)(:?\(\d+\))*
```

- `([A-z]+)` captures the `foo` or any other text that consists of multiple letters and saves it in group 1
- `(:?\(\d+\))*` says `(<1 or more digits>)` 0 or more times

Regular expressions are not designed to compare strings to one another. You can match an input against a pattern.

You can test it against your input here: https://regex101.com/r/MRZxsS/1

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: If you want to use it in java, you need to escape the backslashes in order to squeeze it into a `String`: `"[A-z]+(:?\\(\\d+\\))*"`

Comment: But it doesn't tell if they are all identical. For example, fff should not be treated the same as foo, but foo(3) should be treated the same as foo.

Comment: No. You asked for a regular expression that matches all of your input values, meaning that you can use the regex on all of these sample Strings and the regex matches each one.

Comment: I edited the regex so that the `foo` or `fff` can be retrieved as `matcher.,group(1)` so that you can compare it

Comment: Thank you so much @f1sh!!